# Why isn't assigning c*=40 change the value of a?

Tags: c++, const-cast

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   const int a = 20;
   const int* b = &a;
   cout<<"b* = "<<*b<<"\n";
   int* c=const_cast<int *>(b);
   *c=40;
   cout<<"b* = "<<*b<<" a = "<<a;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should a value of a `const` object change?

Comment: The expression is not as you describe - `*c = 40` (in your code) and `c *= 40` (in the title to the question) mean different things. In any event, you are using `const_cast` to force the compiler to later permit an apparent change of something that is actually `const` - so your code has *undefined* behaviour.   By definition, the C++ standard does not define what happens when behaviour is undefined, so any outcome is possible (e.g. not changing something that you expect to change) and the compiler is not required to emit diagnostics (e.g. errors or warnings) about undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to modify a `const` object, this behaviour is undefined.

From [C++ spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) section 10.1.7.1 point 4

> **any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime results
> in undefined behavior.**

```
const int* ciq = new const int (3);  // initialized as required
int* iq = const_cast<int*>(ciq);     // cast required
*iq = 4;                             // undefined: modifies a const object
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of a is not changing because you are using
const int a = 20;
to change the value of a you can simply declare
int a =20;